# Android coroutine job join confusion

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

so I've been looking at the coroutines for past few days and found quite interesting piece of code

```
val input = MutableStateFlow(5)

lifecycleScope.launch {
    input.collectLatest { 
        val job = launch {
            doSomething1()
            delay(1000L)
            doSomething2()
        }
        job.join()
    }
}
```

I've been debugging it and im not sure why do we need that `job.join` in there, how I understand the whole flow right now:
Lets say we push fast 3 values to `input`, `collectLatest` will terminate previous unfinished box, but since we are launching new coroutine its job is not terminated, so after pushing fast 3 values we will always reach `doSomething2` for each value, if we would skip `launch` inside `collectLatest` we would reach only one `doSomething2` - but now coming to the `job.join` - it should suspend coroutine until the job is done, but since we are not doing anything else in this coroutine is it really needed? Does it give any value? From my tests it doesn't really matter if we have that `job.join` or not, what I am missing in here?

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems like this job.join() is needed to just be sure that this job completes before we do something else, e.g. inside of this collectLatest function. This whole piece of code looks pretty interesting in fact since we don't need collectLatest if we work with each value anyway. Maybe Job.cancelAndJoin() would work better

Comment: I think they're just showing that you would need that line if your coroutine had further work to do after collecting.